# Different usages of would

Tags: modal-verbs, will-would

> Hey, Would you beat your friend for 100 dollars?

What does this mean?

a) Requesting someone to beat his/her friend for 100 dollars?

or

b) Asking whether they would beat his friend for 100 dollars ?

Comment: Grammatically, I think it could technically mean either.  Idiomatically, it would almost definitely mean the second.

Comment: Context is everything. So in a nightclub, *Would you dance with me?* would normally be a (slightly formal) way of ***requesting*** that you dance with the speaker ***right now***. But those same words spoken on the telephone could either be understood as a "future request" (to be enacted at some future time, equivalent to ***Will** you dance with me?*), or a genuine question regarding some hypothetical situation *(Would you dance with me **if we were at a nightclub**?)*.

Comment: "Beat up" would be more usual assuming you're talking about violence.

Answer (score 0):

As stevekeiretsu says, the question could be hypothetical or it could be a request. The grammar is fine. The punctuation and use of capitals is awful! :-)

The question might be simpler if you used 'their' for the person addressed each time:

a) Requesting someone to beat their friend for 100 dollars.
or
b) Asking whether they would beat **their** friend for 100 dollars.